# Can't create *.exe for PyQt5 + pyqtgraph application with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, pyqtgraph

Created a short demo application and I am not able to create a EXE.

Installed packages and their versions

- PyQt5==5.15.7
- pyqtgraph==0.12.3
- pyinstaller==5.5

Tried following command: `pyinstaller --onefile pyqtplot_test.py`

And got this error at the end: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Running the script in command line works as expected.

Could need help for properly creating a runnable executable for Windows. Thanks for help.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import random

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
backend_names = ['Qt5Agg']

class MyPlotWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    UPDATE_TIME = 100

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.graph_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.graph_widget.setBackground("w")

        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]
        self.graph_widget.setXRange(self.x_values[0], self.x_values[-1] + 500, padding=0)
        self.graph_widget.setYRange(min(self.y_values) -100, max(self.y_values) +100, padding=0.1)

        styles = {'color':'k', 'font-size':'15px'}
        self.graph_widget.setLabel('left', '[dec]', **styles)
        self.graph_widget.setLabel('bottom', 'Time in [ms]', **styles)
        self.graph_widget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.graph_widget.addLegend()

        self.data_line1 = self.graph_widget.plot( self.x_values, self.y_values, name="Line", pen=pg.mkPen(color="k", width=2) )

        # update timer
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval( MyPlotWidget.UPDATE_TIME )
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self._update_data)

        # user controls
        self.enable_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Enable")
        self.enable_button.clicked.connect(self._activation_button)

        # overall layout
        widget_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        widget_layout.addWidget(self.graph_widget)
        widget_layout.addWidget(self.enable_button)
        self.setLayout(widget_layout)

    def _activation_button(self):
        if self.enable_button.text() == "Enable":
            self.enable_button.setText("Disable")
            self.enable_button.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgreen")
            self.timer.start()

        elif self.enable_button.text() == "Disable":
            self.enable_button.setText("Enable")
            self.enable_button.setStyleSheet(None)
            self.timer.stop()

    def _update_data(self):
        # update the current data
        # self.y_values = self.y_values[1:] # remove the first element
        # append new values
        self.y_values.append( random.randint(-120,120) ) # add new data point
        # self.x_values = self.x_values[1:] # remove the first element
        self.x_values.append(self.x_values[-1] + MyPlotWidget.UPDATE_TIME) # new value 1 point higher than the last

        if len(self.x_values) > 20:
            start = self.x_values[-20]
        else:
            start = self.x_values[0]
        self.graph_widget.setXRange(start, self.x_values[-1] + 500, padding=0 ) # update the x drawing of window analog to incoming data
        self.data_line1.setData( self.x_values, self.y_values )


class MyTestMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTestMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self._init_ui()

    def _init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("PLOTTING TESTER")
        self.setMinimumSize(640, 480)
        self.plot_widget = MyPlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.plot_widget)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    _ = MyTestMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please run the program from the command prompt to get the full traceback of the error, then [edit] the question and paste it there.

Comment: And this is the problem, the full traceback has to many characters to post it in here. Asking a question is limited to 30000 characters and the traceback of pyinstaller would be about 42k characters, so I desided to share a short example script.

Comment: Well, there's quite a difference between full traceback and no traceback at all. Start by sharing the *last* part of that.